# Alias for bash commands using profile

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, command-line

I need to set up an alias in my profile to chain some console commands together, 
I usually do

```
su root <return> 
<password>
rnd(one more alias just for cd into a particular directory)
```

I want to set up an alias to do all these together, I am new to unix.
Is there anyway to simulate a 'return' in shellscripts?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to store the root password in plain text in your profile?

Comment: correct, Is there a way to do this without losing encryption

Comment: This is a terrible idea. use `sudo` instead. You can configure certain commands to be run with sudo so that you don't need to provide your password.

Comment: But the thing is I have to be root for any changes that i would have to make from that point onwards. I figured this would be easier

Answer (score 0):

This is typically accomplished by

```
alias vault='cd /dragonvault && sudo -u smaug /bin/tcsh'
```

or

```
alias vault='cd /dragonvault && sudo login -l -f smaug'
```

If `smaug` is some administrative account configured with the shell `nologin`, only the first form will work.  For any of these aliases to work, you need to install and configure `sudo` adequately.